# How do I get the beginning of a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, startswith

So... I tried to get what my string starts with and I tried to see if I can get what my string starts with, with the `startswith` function. But as I'm trying to use `startswith` function it just returning True or False.
This is how I tried:

```py
str1 = "sdf fds dfs"
str1.startswith()
```

Comment: _I tried to get what my string starts with_ how do you define `start` - 1, 2, 3...n chars? Have you heard of slicing?

Comment: Have you read what `startswith` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to the above answers, if you want the first word you can use str1.split(" ").

e.g.

```
str1 = "sdf fds dfs"
str1 = str1.split(" ")
print(str1[0])
```

prints sdf

Comment: Thanks! works! This is exactly what I searched for :)

Comment: No problem! Good luck in your project :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following:

```
str1[0]
```

Output:

```
s
```

If you want multiple items, you can use slicing:

```
str1[0:3]
```

Output:

```
sdf
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str1[0]` for the `'s'`

Strings are basically arrays. You can access every character with its position.

You can also select intervals with `:` i.e. `str1[0:5]` get you the first five characters

`startswith(var)` confronts *var* with the first characters i.e. `startswith('sdf')` `startswith('sd')` `startswith('s')` all returns *True*

Some documentations for [strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) and [startswith()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/startswith.html)

Answer (score 0):

It only returns True, or False, because it checks whether string starts with inputed character example:

```
_str = "12345"
print(_str.startswith("a")) # -> False
print(_str.startswith("1")) # -> True
```

So instead use index, e.g:

```
print(_str[0]) # Looking for first character in string.
```

In python and in most programming languages indexing starts from 0, so if you need to get access to the first item you will need to write 0 instead of 1, if you want to access the third item, it will be 2, because it starts like this 0, 1, [2], 3 not 1, 2, [3]